# what does R2 stands for in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

What does R2 stand for in SQL Server 2008 R2?  Is it Revision 2 or Release 2?  Is it an another version with additional features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "R2" suffix in Microsoft-ese stands for "Release 2".  Here is a [link including the full name expansion](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c18bad82-0e5f-4e82-812b-5b23e5d52b9c&displaylang=en).  Microsoft also published a [list of new features in SQL 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500435.aspx).